# Criar ferramenta de polígonos

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular-google-maps

Preciso criar uma ferramenta que desenhe um Polígono usando a ferramenta já existente de polígonos.
Teria um campo `LAT` e `LNG`, onde digitaria os valores e ele vai adicionando os pontos sozinho, sem ter que clicar com o *mouse*.

**[Aqui está o código](https://jsfiddle.net/1ffurnj9/1/)** (é exemplo, não funciona)

Tentei usar o trigger "`click`", mas sem sucesso.
Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Conseguiu Resolver?